# Problems trying to install packages (heavy and Median) in RStudio

Tags: r, package, clang, rstudio, clang++

I am very new to programming and I have probably used the terminal a couple of times in my entire life, both times with someone explaining me what to do. Now I've run into this problem while trying to install some packages in RStudio, and they have explained to me that the Error below means that I have to do something with the clang (word that I had never heard before 3 days ago), so that RStudio can find what it is looking for.

''' /bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++: command not found
make: *** [eigs_gen.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RSpectra’
* removing ‘/Users/beatricenobile/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/RSpectra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RSpectra’ had non-zero exit status '''

Looking over the internet I cannot find anything I understand, and I think I probably don't even know what to look for. So does anybody here have any suggestion or an easy to understand guideline for a solution?

Comment: Are you trying to build the package from source? What did you do before you got the error?

Comment: I don't know what it means to build a package from source,  what I'm doing it typing on the console "install.packages("Gmedian")". And it gives me the same error even if I restart RStudio from zero

Comment: Thats weird.. Can you try `ìnstall.packages("RSpectra")` and post the error message here?

Comment: I solved the problem by disinstalling RStudio and re-installing it again, I still have no idea what was the problem though 
Thank you anyway!